# Deploy .aar file and podspec file using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, aar, podspec

I have build AAR file and Podspec File using Flutter, but I don't know how to deploy on maven or jfrog or some similar repository and podspec for flutter.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you want to upload flutter package on pub?

Comment: no I want to upload flutter module i.e. aar file or podspec file on maven or podspec for public use.

Comment: I can help you but your doubt is not clear, could you please give more details.

Comment: Thanks, @Daljeet I have created an aar file and podspec file using flutter but I don't how I can upload it to maven or similar for IOS.

Comment: @kapilkarda did you uploaded aar files?